# Why am I getting error Thread1 signal: SIGBART in c?

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, runtime-error

My c code for adding strings to array looks like is this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char s[3][10] = {"a","b","c"};
    printf("num:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int i = 0; i< n ; i++)
    {
        printf("new word:");
        getchar();
        scanf("%s", s[i+3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is add new strings to already existing strings in the array i.e after the program is run the s array should be contain the new stirings users has given plus the old strings that were already existing

when I run my program I get the error Thread1 signal: SIGBART after I give the last string for input what is wrong with this code? I am using Xcode but even gcc doesn't solve this so compiler is not at fault at least

I did search on google what this error means and to what I understand it means my code crash due to error in runtime but I couldn't find anything useful to fix it mainly this error comes up in app developing but I am doing c so why is it showing up here??

What is wrong in this code?

I searched on google what is this error and how to fix it needless to say didn't find anything I tried to remove getchars() and use scan("%[^\n]s",s[i+3]) but that also didn't worked I also tried of using int main(void) instead of int main() but that also didn't worked

Comment: You access the array `s` *out of bounds*. That leads to *undefined behavior*. C doesn't have dynamic arrays, you need to explicitly handle any kind of dynamic handling yourself in your code.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `%s` format for `scanf` will skip (ignore) all leading white-space, so you don't need that `getchar` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your access to array "s" is out of bound. You need to reserve space for incoming inputs.

Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  int n;
  char s[10][10] = { "a", "b", "c" };

  printf("num:");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // n must be less than 6
    printf("new word:");
    getchar();
    scanf("%s", s[i + 3]); // input must be less than 10 bytes
  }

  return 0;
}
```

PS: if you really need an unbounded char array, maybe you should consider using std::vector and std::string in c++.